# HTML5 Video styled CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-video

I want to know if there is a possibility to style the HTML5 video player with CSS, or JS? Like more than border and background and if so what attributes you can use...?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Xweque, you should accept the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: Know. I this I might have now... If not, how do I accept... +How do I close a q?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to style the player controls you'll need to implement them yourself. There's a guide here to [implementing custom HTML5 video player controls using jQuery](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/) which should be enough to get you started. You could also consider one of the many [HTML5 video libraries](http://html5video.org/wiki/HTML5_Player_Comparison). These will take care of the custom player control logic for you and allow you to style the controls to the level you require.

Comment: In addition, this is a more up to date list http://html5video.org/wiki/HTML5_Player_Comparison

Comment: Thanks for that Johannes, it looks really useful. I've updated my answer to include the link.